# How to insert a new tag with chosen module ?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I installed the [chosen](https://drupal.org/project/chosen) module and its library on my site drupal 7.

I created a custom field in a content type to enter tags (words) within the vocabulary (taxonomy).

Everything is working correctly for the selection of tag between those in vocabulary, but I can not insert new tags if they do not exist.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module aims to solve that problem.

Autocomplete Deluxe is a replacement for [Chosen](https://drupal.org/project/chosen) module. It has a similar feel to the Chosen module, but allows you to add new tags/terms.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is - both chosen and tag system override html tag with their own functionality. For now chosen does not support freehand writing in it. Unless you can rewrite that part of chosen library, you are stuck, sorry.